# jquery ui autocomplete showing transparent results

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

jquery ui autocomplete showing transparent result. I have applied all the answers which was given different questions on the stackoverflow but didnot worked out.

this is my code

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
     $( "#search" ).autocomplete({

       source: 'scripts/auto.php',

     });

  });
</script>
```

this is the html

```
<div class="container box">

<h2>Search Here</h2>
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search here....">  

</div>
```

this is the php code

```
<?php
include('../admin/functions/dbconfig.php');


    $return_arr = array();
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
    $sql ="SELECT lemma FROM lemma WHERE lemma like '" . $searchTerm . "%' ORDER BY lemma LIMIT 0,6";
    $data = array();
    $q=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $data[] = $row[];
    }
    echo json_encode($data);



    ?>
```

output is like this [image]

Comment: The problem is in your `php` or in your `css` but your information and code are not enough. This is a working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/akL7qfzx/ where I just replaced the css with the `jquery-ui` cdn and the`source` with an array ... it works. First of all try replacing `JQuery-ui CSS` with a `cdn`, and then make sure your `php` returns results.

Comment: Did you check inspect element to see whether there is any data? If data is available then check css `color` property whether it is set as `white` or same as the background color.

Comment: @Baro the results are showing in the ajax response

Comment: @AtiqulAlam i have overridden the background color in the css

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is your css. Obviously we cannot help you if I'm right, we should see the live page or the whole css code. Try to replicate the problem on JSFiddle, you can edit mine.

Comment: @baro I guess the problem is with the php script i am editing the script here please check

Comment: Another thing you can try, type a single character and then use down arrow. If there is available data will show in the input box which is selected after using down arrow. Otherwise your source is not render properly and check is there any console error in the browser.

Comment: @AtiqulAlam there is no error in the console. although i have checked the ajax results , the results are correct.

Comment: Is there any `ul` rendered in your html with class `ui-autocomplete` which has the number of `li` respect to your response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Php is not my first language, I hope it is correct. I try to offer you an alternative, but you must be sure that you query returns results (you should see it by check the rendered HTML, you must have values between square brackets).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<!-- PHP -->

<?php
  include('../admin/functions/dbconfig.php');

  function getArray() {
    $return_arr = array();
    $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
    $sql ="SELECT lemma FROM lemma WHERE lemma like '" . $searchTerm . "%' ORDER BY lemma LIMIT 0,6";
    $data = array();
    $q=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    echo "'" . $row[] . "', "; 
    }
    
  }


?>


<!-- JS -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    
    var availableTags = [<?php getArray(); ?>];

    $("#search").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags  //'scripts/auto.php',
    });

  });
</script>



<!-- HTML -->

<div class="container box">

  <h2>Search Here</h2>
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search here....">

</div>
```